# How to override the default culture (Localization) ABP.IO?

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

How to override the default AbpAccount, AbpValidation, AbpFeatureManagement etc

The config is provided from this endpoint : /api/abp/application-configuration

I have a fr.json file however I am not sure where to place it?

Currentlty everything is shown in English but I want to show it in French

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization)

Comment: I read through that already but I cannot override the default one. The guide only shows how to add a new resource which I got it working, do you know how to get the Identity Server UI Localization working? Assuming it’s also driven by the default ones and I cannot add French json

Comment: you've tagged both `[aspnetboilerplate]` and `[abp]` - try choosing one to get better response

Comment: I am referring here to abp framework, as in http://abp.io

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I create an example to show how to **Extending ABP Existing Resource**

This example is based on the following document
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization#extending-existing-resource

We will change the default `DisplayName:Abp.Timing.Timezone` and `Description:Abp.Timing.Timezone` of `AbpTimingResource` and add localized text in Russian language(`ru`).

I created the `AbpTiming` folder in the `Localization` directory of the `ExtendLocalizationResource.Domain.Shared` project.

Create en.json and ru.json in its directory.

`en.json`

```json
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "DisplayName:Abp.Timing.Timezone": "My Time zone",
    "Description:Abp.Timing.Timezone": "My Application time zone"
  }
}
```

`ru.json`

```json
{
  "culture": "ru",
  "texts": {
    "DisplayName:Abp.Timing.Timezone": "Часовой пояс",
    "Description:Abp.Timing.Timezone": "Часовой пояс приложения"
  }
}
```

Change the code of the `ConfigureServices` method in `ExtendLocalizationResourceDomainSharedModule`.

```cs
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Resources
        .Add<ExtendLocalizationResourceResource>("en")
        .AddBaseTypes(typeof(AbpValidationResource))
        .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/ExtendLocalizationResource");

    //add following code
    options.Resources
        .Get<AbpTimingResource>()
        .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/AbpTiming");

    options.DefaultResourceType = typeof(ExtendLocalizationResourceResource);
});
```

Execute `ExtendLocalizationResource.DbMigrator` to migrate the database and run `ExtendLocalizationResource.Web`.

We have changed the English localization text and added Russian localization.

```
<p>@AbpTimingResource["DisplayName:Abp.Timing.Timezone"]</p>
@using(CultureHelper.Use("ru"))
{
    <p>@AbpTimingResource["DisplayName:Abp.Timing.Timezone"]</p>
}
```

[image]

https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/pull/38

Comment: Worked like a charm! Ta